# Android resize background image in Button

Tags: android, button

my Situation: I have a Backgroundimage and above i have a Transparent Button. Is it possible to zoom in the Backgroundimage inside the Buttonarea ? So it may be just 2% Bigger than next to the Button? Like the Button is a magnifying glass.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button.getLocationOnScreen(int[] location);
width = Button.getWidth()
height = Button.getHeight()

Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BACKGROUND_BITMAP, location[0],    location[1], width, height, null, false);
```

...scale 2%, set as background to the Button